# Getting feature class from Map using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I have an axMapControl.Map, I am trying to get  a featureClass.  I want to use this feature class to call create a GeoProcessor

```
IGeoProcessorResult result = GP.Execute(someFeatureClass, null) as IGeoProcessorResult;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the IMap object you have a ILayer layers collection, search for you layer in that collection. When you find your layer cast it to a IFeatureLayer it has a FeatureClass property.